# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error from setting up iis site

Tags: iis-10

I set up an IIS site today and started getting this error message. Has anyone seen this before? How can I resolved it?[image]

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/oob-500.html

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The deployment of asp.net core to IIS requires the installation of .NET Core Hosting Bundle:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio